# Swift how to set DatePicker to correct TimeZone

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, timezone

I have a DatePicker that only shows Year, Month and Date. The selected Date should always be in UTC TimeZone and be 00:00 of the selected date. For example, if the user selects 01.01.2000, the Date object should be 01.01.2000, 00:00:00, +0000.

I am having issues with my implementation for this. When the user selects 01.01.2000, the resulting Date is 2000-01-01 22:00:00 +0000. Changing the Hour component does not seem to work correctly.

What I have done so far:

1. Set the DatePicker to .gmt TimeZone if available

   ```
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *){
        datePicker.timeZone = .gmt
    }else{
        datePicker.timeZone = .current
    }
   ```

This results in the output above. Trying to fix the hour component, I did:

2. Change Hour and Minute components

   ```
    let myDate = datePicker.date
    print("Selected Date: \(datePicker.date)")

    var calendar = Calendar.current
    var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: myDate)

    // Set the hour and minute components to 0
    components.hour = 0
    components.minute = 0

    // Create the final date with the desired hour
    let finalDate = calendar.date(from: components)
    print("Final Date: \(finalDate!)")
   ```

This however returns 1999-12-31 23:00:00 +0000 which is also wrong. Somehow 23 hours are being subtracted from my original date, just by setting the component to 0. Note that both are in the same timeZone +0000.

What am I doing wrong? I want to make sure that all dates are always 00:00 in UTC Time Zone so that the date is always being displayed correctly, avoiding issues such as the one shown here, where a date could be interpreted as the day before after accounting for the timeZone.

Comment: Why do you set the timezone to `.current` for iOS 15 and earlier? Why aren't you setting it to UTC no matter which version of iOS your app is running under? Change `.current` to `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`.